# Are Struts 2 actions thread safe?

Tags: java, http, web-applications, struts2, thread-safety

It says since Struts 2 actions beans are initialized each request they are thread safe. But what if several threads use this bean within the same HTTP request? So it is not really thread safe right unless we wrote the bean in a thread safe manner?

Below is from struts 2 docs says when compare Struts 1 and Struts 2,

```
Struts 2 Action objects are instantiated for each request, so there are no thread-safety issues
```

[struts 2 documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/comparing-struts-1-and-2.html)

My dought is even Struts 2 Action objects are instantiated for each request still its not thread safe right?

Comment: which bean you are talking about?

Comment: What if does not use? It seems too broad for me. Clarify the question why they are not thread safe. Post a code example to show us if you have one.

Comment: I add more information Roman. Thank You

Comment: Are you talking about conversations? They are thread safe , but not conversation safe. Sharing the same session between browser windows is not safe. In that case you will land up having dirty reads.

Comment: If article would be like this "..there are thread-safety issues" , what you then understood? There are no thread-safety issues means no need to concern for thread safety. Thats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At my point of view a web application is designed using servlet technology. Struts2 support servlet specification at least 2.4. A web server communicates to the client using HTTP protocol and it manages threads.  And you know that no more than one thread is created per request by container. The framework doesn't create any threads except `BackgroundProcess` and it looks like it's doing it in the thread safe manner. You are not responsible to manage action beans, the framework is doing it for you. So, if it claims that it's thread safe you can trust it, or compromise if you have an evidence to opposite. According to this info you can conclude that you can use managed beans that are thread safe.

Comment: So far my comment well, I hava something to say, If In the Action class implement sessionAware to set values in map of session, Is this map a thread safe object?

Comment: @EriksonRodriguez If you have a different question, then you should ask it in the separate thread. This question is asked a decade ago and it contains an accepted answer which you can trust.

Answer (score 1):

For each request new instance of Action class is created. So there is no thread safety issue with struts 2 action class.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is thread safe.

> Struts1 Action Classes are Singleton and not thread safe, that makes extra care on developer side to avoid any side effects because of multithreading. Struts2 action classes gets instantiated per request, so there is no multithreading and makes them thread safe.
>
> [Blockquote](https://www.journaldev.com/2354/struts2-interview-questions-and-answers)